# Redux thunk can't return promise state when I use with spreadsheet api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have getAllSponsorAPI() to call API and get data from the Google spreadsheet, redux async thunk getAllSponsorResponse(). When I dispatched thunk getAllSponsorResponse() the first time, it didn't return the correct promise type (all of them are pending), although I check it in the network and console.log it return fulfilled status. It's only work and the second time, with one click

1. The first time I dispatched thunk
   [I console log it with start and end number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4weA.png)
   [Redux state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTdSu.png)
2. The second time I dispatched think
   [I console log it with start and end number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avyX8.png)
   [Redux state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzWKR.png)

```
export const getAllSponsorAPI = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (window.gapi.client) {
      console.log("start: ", 2);
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          apiKey: config.apiKey,
          discoveryDocs: config.discoveryDocs,
        })
        .then(() => {
          window.gapi.client.load("sheets", "v4", () => {
            window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values
              .get({
                spreadsheetId: config.spreadsheetId,
                range: "Sheet1!A1:T",
              })
              .then(
                (response: any) => {
                  let data: any = [];
                  const values = response.result.values;
                  const dataHeader = values[0];
                  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                    let obj = {};
                    dataHeader.forEach((ele: string, idx: number) => {
                      obj = { ...obj, [ele]: values[i][idx] };
                    });
                    data.push(obj);
                  }
                  resolve(data);
                },
                (response: any) => {
                  reject(response.result.error);
                }
              );
          });
        });
    }
  });
  console.log("getAllSponsorAPI: ", promise);
  return promise;
  // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
};
```

```
export const getAllSponsorResponse = createAsyncThunk(
  "sponsors/getAllSponsors",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    console.log("start: ", 1);
    await window.gapi.load("client", getAllSponsorAPI);
    const response = await getAllSponsorAPI();
    console.log("end: ", 1);
    console.log("response: ", response);
    return response;
  }
);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllSponsorResponse());
  }, []);
```

I expect when the page load first time, it's call API, put data into redux

Comment: It will probably do that - but it won't pause your render, and `useEffect` will also only do this *after* your first render.